# Using Riverpod CRUD API DATA

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am updating my App and wanted to add State Management with [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/).
I want to do [CRUD](https://www.codecademy.com/article/what-is-crud) operations data from API endpoint.

So far I am not able to get things right and working properly

## Here is what I have so far..

#### API Class

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MyApiClass {

    final String _url = 'http://website.test/api/';

    getMethod(apiUrl) async {
       var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl;
       return await http.get( Uri.parse(fullUrl), headers: _setHeaders() );
    }
}
```

#### Provider File

```dart
import '../api/api.dart';
import '../models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class UserAPINotifier {
  Future<UserModel> getSingleUser() async {
    return await MyApiClass().getMethod('auth/me');
  }
}

final userDataProvider = Provider((ref) => UserAPINotifier());

final userProv = FutureProvider<UserModel>((ref) {
  return ref.read(userDataProvider).getSingleUser();
});
```

#### Profile Screen

```dart
...//

class ProfileScreen extends ConsumerWidget {

    Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
      final user = ref.read(userProv);
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(${user.name} ) )
      )
    }
}
```

## My Question

How can I use Riverpod in a proper manner following the approach I have used

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display user informations in your ProfileScreen

```
class ProfileScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final userReq = ref.watch(userProv);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Profile")),
      body: userReq.when(
        data: (user) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'User ID: ${user?.uid ?? "N/A"}',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                Text(
                  'Email: ${user?.email ?? "N/A"}',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                Text(
                  'Display Name: ${user?.displayName ?? "N/A"}',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                Text(
                  'Phone Number: ${user?.phoneNumber ?? "N/A"}',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                Text(
                  'Email Verified: ${user?.emailVerified ?? false}',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        error: (error, stackTrace) {
          return Text('Error: $error');
        },
        loading: () =>
            const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.blueAccent),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```